# how to send a string from child to parent using pipe

Tags: c++, string, pipe

I'm trying to send a string from the `parent[0]` to the `child[1]`. The string has a fixed size so everytime the length can be different.

parent:

```
std::string x;
while(read(fd[WRITE_FD], &x, x.length()) > 0)
    {
      cout<< x;
    }
```

Comment: please check argument types of the `read` and `write` functions.

Comment: `read(fd[WRITE_FD], &x, x.length());` you can't do that with a string,

Comment: `read(fd[WRITE_FD], &x, x.length());` if the 2nd argument was valid x.length() would still be 0.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::string` is not suitable as the second argument to `read`.  You need to pass `read` a buffer into which to write its data along with a number of bytes to read from the pipe.

You'll make your life much simpler if you write the length of the string to the pipe first.  That way you can know how many bytes to read from the pipe:

```
int main() {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        std::string str = "some data";
        std::string::size_type size = str.size();
        write(fd[1], &size, sizeof(size));
        write(fd[1], str.c_str(), str.size());
    } else {
        close(fd[1]);
        std::string::size_type size;
        read(fd[0], &size, sizeof(size));
        std::string str(size, ' ');
        // This depends on the fact that the pointer returned by data
        // is non-const in C++17.
        // Use &str[0] instead of str.data() if using an older C++ standard
        read(fd[0], str.data(), size);
    }
}
```

In this example, the child process first writes the length of the string to the pipe, then the string data itself (notably, it does not write the nul-terminator to the pipe).  The parent then reads the length, allocates an appropriately-sized string, and reads data into the buffer managed by that string.

---

If you don't want to write the string's length first, you'll have to read a chunk at a time until you find a chunk that ends with a nul byte:

```
int main() {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        std::string str = "some data";
        write(fd[1], str.c_str(), str.size() + 1);
    } else {
        close(fd[1]);
        std::string str;
        while (true) {
            char c[100];
            ssize_t count = read(fd[0], c, 100);
            if (c[count - 1] == '\0') {
                // Don't copy an extra nul terminator into the string object
                str.append(c, c + count - 1);
                break;
            } else {
                str.append(c, c + count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the child process writes the string data to the pipe with a nul-terminator.  The parent process then reads from the pipe in 100-byte chunks, appending the data to the string until it reads a chunk that ends with a nul byte.

Comment: Everything work great beside `read(fd[WRITE_FD], str.data(), size);`

Comment: @ItayGoldfaden Did you read the comment above that line?  If you aren't using C++17, you will need to use `&str[0]` instead since `std::string::data` returns a `const char*`.  If that's not the problem you'll need to be more specific with exactly what error you're seeing.